# single back slash and double back slash in #define statement, and what is the starting .L for singal names? (arm64 assembly)

Tags: assembly, c-preprocessor, arm64

This is a code from linux 5.4.21.

```
==== ./arch/arm64/include/asm/sysreg.h

#define __DEFINE_MRS_MSR_S_REGNUM               \
"   .irp    num,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30\n" \
"   .equ    .L__reg_num_x\\num, \\num\n"            \
"   .endr\n"                        \
"   .equ    .L__reg_num_xzr, 31\n"
```

In __DEFINE_MRS_MSR_S_REGNUM, I understand `.irp` and `.equ` directive. But why does it use `\\num` instead of `\num`? I guess it's for escaping before special characters because `\` is a special character and the preprecessor makes it `.L__reg_num_x\num, \num`. But why is `\n` using single back-slash then? Is it specially processed during preprocessing?
And another question is : what is that `.L` in front of symbol name in `.equ` statements? Does it have any special meaning, or is it just to express it's a long value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.L` is a file-local label, no visible in the symbol table.  https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/L.html.

As for the `\num` after the C preprocessor is done expanding it, again read the GAS manual: https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Irp.html `.irp` takes a parameter name to be expanded inside the macro.  GAS macros in general use `\name` for `.macro` as well.

Comment: I see, the \\num because num is a parameter. \n because it's a special newline character. Thank you!

Comment: @ChanKim: Oh, this #define looks like it's intended for use as part of an `asm("template")` statement, where multiple lines of asm inside one concatenated string literal are ended by `"\n"`.  (Rather than included into a `.S`).  That would explain the `""`.  So the `\\` is to get a literal backslash into the string literal, that will become part of the compiler's asm output.